# Objective C++ support in autotools

Tags: autotools, objective-c++

I'm working under Mac OS X 10.6.5
autoconf version 2.68
automake version 1.11.1
In a large project that is built using autoconf, automake, I need to add .mm files to the library sources. When I add them to the library_SOURCES variable they won't compile even after  I use

```
AS_IF([test "$with_target" = "quartz"], [AC_PROG_OBJCXX])
```

in my configure.ac. The test is passed successfully and it event outputs

```
checking whether we are using the GNU Objective C++ compiler... yes
```

and .mm files don't compile. Where can I look to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with custom suffix rule:

```
$ cat Makefile.am

.mm.o :
  $(CXXCOMPILE) -x objective-c++ -с $< -o $@

bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = foo.mm bar.m baz.cpp
```

BTW, if *.o from *.mm are placed in library, i failed to link target binary properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I finally used a suffix rule, but I need to link it into library too. It links, but some strange run-time problems start to appear within the code defined in .mm file, like 2 constructors with same signature but on different memory addresses, and overwriting class members in the code which doesn't know about this class. What were your problems with linking mm's into library?

Comment: It seems automake does not explicitly support ObjC++ yet.

Comment: how can you pass target-specific flags to this target? I mean let's say I have two targets which both contain .mm sources and now I'd like to pass their's OBJCFLAGS to this new .mm.o: target. How can I achieve this? As target-specific flags are stored like target_name_OBJCFLAGS but this .mm.o target should serve different program targets...

Comment: for those interested: I've ended up creating a separate folder for objective-c sources and wrote simple Makefile.am which has noinst_LIBRARIES target which builds all the .mm sources into .a archive which is added to the program_LIBADD flags in the top-level Makefile.am so that main app can be linked against it.

Comment: @peetonn can you post some snippet code about how you did it?